# Accessing different widget attributes in a given widget

Tags: python, kivy

Need to know how to access widget attributes from different attributes in kv language. I have a different application, will present a simpler version.

Not very sure of how to use widget tree id referencing or app or root. Nothing helped.

in my kv file

- Widget 1  which is the root, has two widgets widget2, widget3.
- widget 2 has an attribute var1
- Widget 3 has a widget whose attribute var2 should change with variation in var1 value

Comment: eyllanesc, thank you for editing my question.

Answer (score 0):

With id's.

```
rootWidget:    
    Widget1:
        id: w1
        Widget2:
            id: w2
        Widget3:
            id: w3
    Widget4:
        id: w4
```

You can access those three widgets in kv now:

```
root.orientation = "vertical"
w1.orientation = "vertical" "if this is a label for example" 
w2.text = "if this is a label for example"
w3.property = something
w4.property = something
```

Comment: Thanks. Say I have Another widget widget 4 in same level as widget 1. How do I access widget 4's attribute in widget 2 ?

Comment: Is widget 4 the root of the app, or what is it a part of?

Comment: @Sarala you need to edit the question to what you want to ask about or ask a new question. And provide an example that is runnable that shows the issue you have. As is now, the answer answers your question.

Comment: widget 4 is a child widget like widget 1. Both have a root widget, which is the base.

Comment: @Sarala ok got it. updated. And you can keep on going like that. nest to infinity.